# How can I get a trading view post request to my nodejs app

Tags: node.js, express, http-post

I have a nodeJS app for getting a post request from TV. TV sends to my app a POST request with data and application/json headers, but in my app, I get an empty req.body. I use `app.use(express.json())`

Example of TV request

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' -d '{"text": "BTCUSD Greater Than 9000"}' -X POST https://webhook.site/test
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple express server that I tested with, I used your curl and hit my api, seems to be working fine.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/test', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    return res.status(200).json({ ok: true });
});
const port = 8080;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server connected at ${port}`, 'server_start'));
```

Comment: It's not worked for me ( req.body is empty

Comment: when you say empty, is it an empty object? What does your req body have in it?